# Recording selenium tests for video playback (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, selenium, ffmpeg, webdriver

I am trying to implement recording tests for playback using Java/Ubuntu and ffmpeg/x11grab. We often launch multiple tests on a box (via grid2) and was wondering is there anyway to have ffmpeg/x11grab record each window and not the entire desktop in case the windows are overlapped.

What are other options for recording selenium tests so they can be played back?

Answer (score 0):

You can always run the tests on a graphical machine and record the output. If you are running the tests on an x server try checking this out.

http://www.jedi.be/blog/2010/08/30/capturing-the-screen-of-your-virtual-machines-using-x-vnc-rdp-or-native/